# Анимация при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь при решение следующей задачи. Собственно задача заключается в том, что проскролив определённое кол-во пикселей вниз, происходило плавное анимирование числа. Для этого я написал функцию, в которую передаются два параметра: селектор и количество пикселей которые нужно проскролить вниз, чтобы функция отработала. Проблема возникает тогда, когда мы доскролили до нужного блока, а потом опять начинаем скролить вверх

```js
 function Counter(selector, height) {
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() < height ) {
                $(selector).each(function () {
                    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                        Counter: $(this).text()
                    }, {
                        duration: 1000,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        step: function (now) {
                            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                        }
                    });
                });      
            }
        }
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
  Counter(".block-sale__number", "700");
  Counter(".buy-program-info__middle span", "1199");
});
```

```css
.block-sale__number {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.buy-program-info__middle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
}
p {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:600px;
  background: #FEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-sale__number">1000</div>
<div class="buy-program-info__middle"><span>10000</span></div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на сниппет - воспроизводится ли в нём ваша проблема?

Comment: Из-за `$(window).scrollTop() < height` у вас анимация начинается после первого же скролла, что не соотвтествует вашей задумке, судя по описанию вопроса.

Comment: Изменил в коде на `$(window).scrollTop() == height`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Исправляем условие, нам нужно начать анимацию после того, как доскроллили до нужной точки, т.е. всё-таки `$(window).scrollTop() >= height`
- Есть проблема в том, что иницируется запуск новой анимации после того, как уже одна анимация стартовала. Блокируем повторные запуски анимации с помощью data-атрибута.

```js
function Counter(selector, height) {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= height) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
      var $t = $(this);
      if (!$t.data('fired')) {
        $t.data('fired', true);
        $t.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: $t.text()
        }, {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'linear',
          step: function(now) {
            $t.text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  Counter(".block-sale__number", "700");
  Counter(".buy-program-info__middle span", "1199");
});
```

```css
.block-sale__number {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.buy-program-info__middle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 600px;
  background: #FEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-sale__number">1000</div>
<div class="buy-program-info__middle"><span>10000</span></div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!